# lock screen takes time to show

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, lock-screen

When I leave my desktop I lock it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. When I Use Windows or Gnome-shell the lockscreen shows instantaneously and I can leave my desk. When I use Unity it takes a few seconds until the lockscreen appears and The lockscreen uses an fade-in animation to show. Every time this happens I am insecure if the shortcut worked and I have to look back at my desk before leaving the room if it realy is locked.

Is there a way to shorten this time or at least disable the animation so that it switches to the lockscreen instantaneously?

Comment: Check whether the following is installed under your user name ll | grep '.Xauthority', if not install under your user name and check the speed of the lock screen.

Comment: Please check https://askubuntu.com/questions/881125/time-to-lock-desktop and https://askubuntu.com/questions/907323/how-do-i-reduce-delay-before-locking-after-pressing-lock-button/